# Assign from object to a class instance

Tags: c#, using, assign, objectname

I have a Class `Dogs`, and one of its properties is called `MyPictureBox` (type of `PictureBox`). I also have four picture boxes on the windows form.

I have this piece of code assigning corresponding `pictureBox`es to the instance of each `Dog`. And this works just fine.

```
Dogs[0].MyPictureBox = pictureBoxDog1;
Dogs[1].MyPictureBox = pictureBoxDog2;
Dogs[2].MyPictureBox = pictureBoxDog3;
Dogs[3].MyPictureBox = pictureBoxDog4;
```

I spent some time trying to cycle through Dogs and assign `pictureBox` using its name (as the only difference in picture box name is the ending 1,2,3,4) with no luck.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated (hate to move ahead without solving this first).

Comment: You haven't tagged the language you work in, and I can't really see a question – you should [edit] it to say what specifically you're expecting to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: "Any ideas are greatly appreciated" --- how about this: ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can get from your question, I think your `dog` should have a method like `showOnPictureBox(PictureBox p)` and maybe a property that holds the PictureBox that the dog is currently "*in*".